# php, simple preg_match_all example not working

Tags: php, preg-match-all

It seems like the preg_match is working until it finds the first match and then stops:

```
$bgStr="<><><><><><><>";


$regStr='/</';

preg_match_all($regStr,$bgStr,$matches);

echo count($matches);
```

gives me the result of:  "1".  What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing that `preg_match_all()` returns a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: got it!!! thanks!!:  echo count($matches[0])  gives me "5"

Comment: Actually just `echo preg_match_all($regStr,$bgStr)` will give you 5.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 logical ways to achieve your count on the less than symbol.
The last one listed being the best / most efficient / recommended one...

[preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is overkill.  *It creates an array in an array containing elements which must be counted.*

```
$bgStr="<><><><><><><>";
if(preg_match_all('/</',$bgStr,$matches)){
    echo sizeof($matches[0]);  // counts the fullstring elements that preg_match_all creates
}
```

[count_chars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php) is overkill.  *It creates an array of elements like `CodeNumber=>Count` for each character found in the string.*

```
$bgStr="<><><><><><><>";
echo count_chars($bgStr,1)[60];
```

> [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) is the leanest method and was specifically
>   designed for this purpose.  *This is a single-function, one-liner that
>   does not generate excess data nor requires additional variables.*
>
> ```
> $bgStr="<><><><><><><>";
> echo substr_count($bgStr,'<');
> ```

All methods above will output: `7`

Comment: @rikkitikkitumbo I wanted to get some resolution on your question.  I've provided three different methods for achieving your desired result.  If you are satisfied with it, please award it the green tick so that future SO readers can benefit from it.  If not, please leave me a comment explaining the issue.